# Diffrence between 'compared to' and 'compared with'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, prepositions, verb-agreement, parts-of-speech

> The gross NPA ratio as of end Dec. was  13 % as compared with 8 % a year earlier .

What would be the difference if I wrote *compared to* in this sentence?

Please explain the use of *compare to* and *compared with*.

Comment: Please fix your title (it should be a question), rewrite your post so it is readable, and refrain from using abbreviations such as "plz." Please.

Comment: I think that you're right about the duplicate, Teacher KSHuang, and I've voted to close this question as a duplicate—but the answers posted beneath the earlier question are not terribly impressive. It would be interesting to read a more thorough account of what various authorities agree on and disagree on with regard to how the two phrases differ.

Comment: I think *as compared to* is a set phrase, so it might not be directly related to the preposition used when *compare* is a more active verb.

Comment: The answer to the post “Compared with” vs “Compared to”—which is used when?" is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I should note that both can be used to point out differences or similarities.

When we **compare** something **with** something else, we are not expressing opinions or making personal statements. We are placing two things side by side and noting **empirical similarities and differences**. Our purpose is to be fair and impartial. **The accuracy or inaccuracy of our findings can be verified.**

Here is an example from OED

> These mountains do not compare with the Himalayas

The act of **comparing to**—claiming that two distinct entities share a noteworthy similarity—is something children do all the time. When a child says, “**Mommy, that owl looks like Uncle Al!**” she is **comparing** her uncle’s face **to** a bird’s. That is not exactly in-depth analysis.

Another example from OED:

> I've had some difficulties but the were nothing compared to yours

Extracted from [grammarbook](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/compare-to-vs-compare-with/)

Comment: How does this answer relate to the specific sentence in the question?

Comment: @Barmar  OP asks for an explanation about the difference between two. I think the explanation is clear enough about the usage of "compare to/with"  in my answer.

Comment: The sentence in OP's question conforms with the first part of my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

*as compared to* and *as compared with* mean essentially the same thing. These days *as compared to* is a bit more common, but a few decades *as compared with* was far more popular.

[image]

Comment: Yes and don't those OED references trip over a bit of a molehill if *These difficulties were nothing compared to those*?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I think we're specifically talking about the phrase when preceded by "as". It's different in other uses.

Comment: Really? I was trying to support you but *as* changes everything? I think not and whatever I thought, I think you can't support *we're specifically talking about the phrase when preceded by 'as'* from the OP.

Feel free to try, though…